# Tomography library in Qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, state-tomography

I am wondering what is the equivalent to the import bellow in the current version of Qiskit?

```
import qiskit.tools.qcvv.tomography as tomography
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The import should be replaced by:

```
import qiskit.ignis.verification.tomography as tomo
```

As documented [here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/release_notes.html#release-notes-0-9-0-upgrade-notes)